# ASP DropDown causing ViewState to appear in Address bar

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, postback, autopostback

If you visit [this page](http://www.maplesoft.com/company/news/index.aspx) in Internet explorer, and choose a value from the "Current Media Releases" dropdown on the top right, eventually IE will try to redirect you to an ugly url containing this string:

__EVENTTARGET=selArchives&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=

The page should only be updating the selArchives Query string value.

The drop down has AutoPostBack set to true and the codebehind is in VB, here is the event handler:

```
Private Sub selArchives_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles selArchives.SelectedIndexChanged
    Response.Redirect("index.aspx?selArchives=" + selArchives.SelectedValue)
End Sub
```

Obviously, I could just write the JavaScript myself, but I would like to find the source of the problem.

---

Not sure what specifically was causing the problem. Looks like it was a combination of a few factors.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your page has javascript errors.  Please fix them.

Second, you only see the ugly url when you select a date and click the go button.  But you've got the dropdown set to auto postback.  Ditch the button; you don't need it.

There's something screwy with the button in your codebehind.  And the dropdown, as well, since it stops working after a few uses.

You'll have to post your page's source for any more help.

Answer (score 1):

Went to the site.  Other than some javascript errors that are popping, it appears to be working fine.

==
Error: $ is not defined
Source file: http://www.maplesoft.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=kNY1h-WYJzKkuCdZqmndbpb67jRr2cZCC6s2tf_nrnwCcH6rvds1RZUYXUp0gdMqnu-6-o6rl1eH-wm7AO9xVw2&t=633640679588907500

## Line: 1

Answer (score 0):

The problem only occurs in IE. It works fine in Firefox, and obviously Chrome as well.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me also IE7 on XP2.

However there is an object expected error onload.  $ is not defined.